# It is possible to use dual-screen RDP for an Ubuntu 23 desktop VM?

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, virtualization, remote-desktop

I have an Ubuntu 23 desktop VM in VMware vSphere. I already set the virtual video card to have two displays and 128 MB of video memory.

However, when I RDP to it (ensuring "use all monitors" is checked) I only get one screen. To my knowledge, I've done everything that should be needed but this still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a Ubuntu 23 Desktop; there are two releases in 2023; one in October (23.10) and an earlier release in April (23.04), with the *year* format reserved for *snap* only releases of Ubuntu Server (eg. Ubuntu Core 22 being the 2022 release). What do **you** mean by 23 Desktop as there is no such thing (23.04 & 23.10 used different GNOME version desktops)